# Heap growth after returning to baseline state

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to understand why instruments is saying the indicated lines in the following code is causing dirty memory growth.  I am getting this in my second heap shot (after the baseline) after returning to the baseline state.  Can anyone point out my error?

```
CCSprite *baseSprite = NULL;
CCSprite *mainHandSprite = NULL;
CCSprite *offHandSprite = NULL;
CCSprite *helmetSprite = NULL;
CCSprite *torsoSprite = NULL;
CCSprite *gloveSprite = NULL;
CCSprite *bootSprite = NULL;

NSString* afile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i.PNG", file, num];
baseSprite = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:afile];   /* HEAP GROWTH */
baseSprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);

int w = baseSprite.textureRect.size.width;
int h = baseSprite.textureRect.size.height;

mainHandSprite = [self mainHandSprite:file And:num];
helmetSprite = [self headSprite:file And:num];
torsoSprite = [self torsoSprite:file And:num];
offHandSprite = [self shieldSprite:file And:num];
gloveSprite = [self gloveSprite:file And:num];
bootSprite = [self bootSprite:file And:num];

CCRenderTexture *rt = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:w height:h]; /*HEAP GROWTH */

[rt begin];

[baseSprite visit];
if (torsoSprite)
    [torsoSprite visit];
if (helmetSprite)
    [helmetSprite visit];
if (offHandSprite)
    [offHandSprite visit];
if (bootSprite)
    [bootSprite visit];
if (gloveSprite)
    [gloveSprite visit];
if (mainHandSprite)
    [mainHandSprite visit];

[rt end];

CCTexture2D *aTex = rt.sprite.texture;
[aTex setAntiAliasTexParameters];

[baseSprite release];
baseSprite = NULL;
[mainHandSprite release];
mainHandSprite = NULL;
[torsoSprite release];
torsoSprite = NULL;
[helmetSprite release];
helmetSprite = NULL;
[offHandSprite release];
offHandSprite = NULL;
[gloveSprite release];
gloveSprite = NULL;
[bootSprite release];
bootSprite = NULL;

return aTex;
```

Comment: You generally need to do three of four heap shots.

Comment: If you haven't already see: [bbum blog](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/)

Comment: I've looked at that before and that's exactly what I did to isolate the exact lines of code that are causing the growth.  My problem is not understanding why they are causing growth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message just states where the instance is created not where it is leaked.

The variable `baseSprite` is retained elsewhere without a balancing release.

For `rt` either `CCRenderTexture` returns an un-autoreleased object or the variable is retained elsewhere without a balancing release.

If you need to see where retains, releases and autoreleases occur for an object use instruments:

Run in instruments, in Allocations set "Record reference counts" on on (you have to stop recording to set the option). Cause the problem code to run, stop recording, search for there ivar of interest, drill down and you will be able to see where all retains, releases and autoreleases occurred.

[image]

Comment: Right.  Any idea how I track the retains/releases or do I have to manually plod through the code?

Comment: Ok.  That answers this question, but doing that I still cant figure out an extra retain even though I see the line of code.  I'll post that as a separate question.  Thank you.